# Think in python, Chapter 8(lists)

Tags: python, list

As an exercise, describe the relationship

between *string.join(string.split(song))* and *song*.

(they both refer to a string)

**Are they the same for all strings? When would they be different?**

I am a little ashamed to ask such a question for a likely simple question but,

I don't get it, what is/are the exception(s)? when are they are different?

Comment: Step 1.  Write some code to try things out.  Step 2.  Update the question with the code you tried.  It's easier to comment on real code.  Please update the question with real code that attempts to answer the question.

Comment: The string module functions are deprecated, by the way. Which edition of Thinking in Python is this?

Comment: Experience is the best teacher. First of all, read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to understand what the functions do. Then try it out with a variety of strings. From there you can deduce an empirical rule and answer your own question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default [the `split` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) groups consecutive delimiters together, so if you have them in your original string they'll be lost:

```
>>> import string
>>> song = "I     am      the      Walrus"
>>> string.join(string.split(song))
'I am the Walrus'
```

However, if you specify delimiters to split on then consecutive delimiters are not grouped so you can keep the strings the same:

```
>>> string.join(string.split(song,' '))
'I   am    the    Walrus'
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` actually splits on one or more occurrences of the delimiter. So `" a   b        c ".split()` and "a b c".split() both result in the same `list` i.e. `['a','b','c']`. `join` only adds a single instance of the delimiter in between consecutive elements of the `list`. " ".join(['a','b','c'])`gives us`"a b c"`, which matches out second string but not the first string.

```
>>> original="     a        b           c    "
>>> " ".join(original.split())
'a b c'
```

BTW, using `string.split` and `string.join` is deprecated. Simply call them as methods of the string you are working on (as in my examples).

Comment: without arguments, it also splits on newlines and tabs.

Comment: @Marco Mariani: yes, without arguments it just splits on all whitespace.